Want to fetch data when page load and store it in cache and when i reload the page i should not fetch again using tanstack query next js 14
//tanstackqueryProvider
'use client'

import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider, useQueryClient } from '@tanstack/react-query'

function Providers({ children }: React.PropsWithChildren) {
 const queryClient = new QueryClient()

  return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
       {children}
    </QueryClientProvider>
  )
}

export default Providers

//layout.tsx
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import "./globals.css";
import { HydrationBoundary, QueryClient, dehydrate } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import Providers from "@/providers/TanstackProvider";
import { cache } from "react";
import { ReactQueryDevtools } from "@tanstack/react-query-devtools";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Create Next App",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default async function RootLayout({children}: {children: React.ReactNode}) {
  const queryClient = cache(() => new QueryClient({
    defaultOptions: {
      queries: {
        refetchInterval: 10000,
        staleTime: 5000
      }
    }
  })); 
  const dehydratedState = dehydrate(queryClient());

  return (
    <html>
      <body>
          <Providers>
            <HydrationBoundary state={dehydratedState} >
               {children}
            </HydrationBoundary>
            <ReactQueryDevtools initialIsOpen={false}/>
          </Providers>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}

//fetchUsers.tsx
export async function fetchUsers() {
    try {
      const res = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");
      return await res.json()
    } catch (err: any) {
      throw err.response.data
    }
  }

//app/page.tsx
"use client"
import { QueryClient, useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import { fetchUsers } from "./fetchUsers";


const Home = () => {
  const queryClient = new QueryClient();
  const { isLoading, error, data } = useQuery(
    {
      queryKey:["users"],
      queryFn:fetchUsers,
    }
  );

  return (
    <div>
      {isLoading && <div>Loading...</div>}
      {error && <div>Error: {error.message}</div>}
      {data && (
        <ul>
          {data.map((user:any) => (
            <li key={user?.title}>{user.title}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;

Here i am trying to do that i am fetching the data of posts in my page.tsx and it fetched but the thing is when i reload my page give a new request to the backend and fetch new posts every time i dont want that i want to make it as quick as i can using the cache

you have to persist data in localestorage for that . read this https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/framework/react/plugins/persistQueryClient

The queryCache lives in memory only. If you reload the page, the cache is gone. If you want, you can use the persister plugin to store the cache in e.g. localstorage: https://tanstack.com/query/v5/docs/framework/react/plugins/persistQueryClient
